# Store Elements in 2 column with TableLayout

Tags: android

I have a problem with TableLayout because I want to store an imageview and textview in 2 columns but my page shown in 2 rows
my sample code is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <TableRow 
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content">
   <TextView 
android:id="@+id/tv_country"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12dp" 
android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
       <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_country_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can write code like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#767676" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#565656" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_country_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

I use temp color to show differences.
Here output layout will look like..

[image]

I hope this will helpful.

Comment: I tried it, it shown in 2 rows ! I use this page as ListView

Comment: mine XML code is proper, you might have two items in listview !! Or something wrong in your java code.

Comment: yes, xml is ok, can I send my code for you with email please?